# Why a list is updated in a recursive call?

Tags: python

I have a graph represented by a dictionary with this values:

```
self.dicpre: {0: [1, 2], 1: [2]}
```

What the `dicpre` is representing is that node 0 has two children (node 1 and 2), and node 1 has one children (node 2).

I'm using a recursive function to check if there is a close-loop (direction matters in this case) based on DFS. For doing that, I'm using a vector `need` to check if I visited that node before. If I start with the vector with all zeros:

```
need = [0]*numNodes
```

and I call the recursive fuction:

```
self.doCourse(node,need)
```

The fuction is like this:

```
def doCourse(self, node: int, need: List[int]) -> bool:
    if need[node] == 1:
        return False
    else:
        need[node] = 1
    if node in self.dicpre:
        for c in self.dicpre[node]:
            if not self.doCourse(c,need):
                return False

    return True
```

So first I visit node 0 then node 1 (children from 0) and then node 2 (children from 1). Because node 2 have no children, I come back to node 0 and visit its other children which is node 2 again. What I expected to see for each call to the fuction would be:

```
1- For Node 0, need = [1,0,0]
2- For Node 1, need = [1,1,0]
3- For Node 2, need = [1,1,1]
4- Come back to the Node 0 call (and then need whould be reset) and visit Node 2 again so need = [1,0,1]
```

However, when I come back to the node 0 to visit node 2, the `need` vector is not reset and I have:

```
Node 0, need = [1, 0, 0]
Node 1, need =[1, 1, 0]
Node 2, need =[1, 1, 1]
Node 2, need = [1, 1, 1]
```

I thought that when you call a recursive function, you stack all the variables in memory, but this is not the case because the vector `need` does not return to its original value.

Am I missunderstanding something here?
Thanks a lot

Comment: The list object only exists once and gets modified, as you never make a copy of it but only pass that one object around.

Comment: This is because your variable is not called by value, it is called by reference.

When you create a non-trivial value it is constructed on the heap.